# How do I remove all commas from a text column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql, replace

I have a table called 'master' such as:

| item | cost |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 4.47 |
| car | 7,232.64 |
| bike | 499.99 |

Currently item and cost are both TEXT data types. I want to convert cost to NUMERIC but get an error because of the comma in the car price.

How can I remove ALL commas from the cost column?

```
dbname=# ALTER TABLE master ALTER COLUMN cost TYPE numeric USING cost::numeric;
```

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "7,232.64"

Comment: Replace them with empty strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`regexp_replace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

```
UPDATE master SET cost = regexp_replace(cost, ',', '', 'g');
```